# how to set a text centered over an image by his alt tag

Tags: jquery, html, hover, center

I need to put over a -responsive- image a string like "video", which is also his alt tag.
for example:

```
<img src="my_image" alt="VIDEO">
```

and i should have my image and in the center (vertical and horizontal) the string "VIDEO" used as alt.
I don't know how to use jquery, i've searched a lot but nothing is exactly what i need.

**See that I don't need a CSS solution!**

I've my reason, but I need jquery solution. I've tryed but nothing...
If I write:

```
<script>

    $(function () {
        var info = $("#informa");
        if (info.length == 0) {
            info = $("<span />").addClass("informa");
            $("body").append(info);
        }
        info.hide();
        $(".hover_text").bind("mouseenter", function () {
            var p = GetScreenCordinates(this);
            info.html(this.alt);
            info.show();
            info.css("width", $(this).width());
            info.css({ "left": p.x, "top": p.y + this.offsetHeight - info[0].offsetHeight });
        });
        $(".hover_text").bind("mouseleave", function () {
            info.hide();
        });
    });
    function GetScreenCordinates(obj) {
        var p = {};
        p.x = obj.offsetLeft;
        p.y = obj.offsetTop;
        while (obj.offsetParent) {
            p.x = p.x + obj.offsetParent.offsetLeft;
            p.y = p.y + obj.offsetParent.offsetTop;
            if (obj == document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0]) {
                break;
            }
            else {
                obj = obj.offsetParent;
            }
        }
        return p;
    }
</script>
```

and my image is:

```
                <img src="myimage.jpg" class="hover_text" alt="Collection">
```

it appears right but in the top.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add absolute positioning to the `span`, to remove it from the regular text flow. Add the following line:

```
info.css("position", "absolute");
```

And you get your `span` above your image. The positioning is just a matter of correct calculation.

---

**Edit:**

To center it horizontally, just add `text-align: center` to the element, since it is already as wide as the image by doing this `info.css("width", $(this).width());`. For vertical centering, i assume that it can have multiple lines, so you need to add half of the height of the image and then substract half of the height of the text on the image.

Full code here: http://jsfiddle.net/sQwW6/

Edited lines:

```
info.css("text-align", "center");
info.css({ "left": p.x, "top": p.y + $(this).height()/2 - info.height()/2 });
```

Comment: could you write me the correct code so i will accept your answer? 'cause i need it to be centerized and i really don't know how-to do, thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

`Use this modified script:`

```
    $(function () {
        var info = $("#informa");
        if (info.length == 0) {
            info = $("").addClass("informa");
            $("body").append(info);
        }
        info.hide();
        $(".hover_text").bind("mouseenter", function () {
            var p = GetScreenCordinates(this);
            info.html(this.alt);
            info.show();
            info.css("width", $(this).width());
            info.css("position",'absolute');
            info.css({ "top": info[0].offsetWidth-p.x, "left": p.y  - info[0].offsetHeight });
        });
        $(".hover_text").bind("mouseleave", function () {
            //info.hide();
        });
    });
    function GetScreenCordinates(obj) {
        var p = {};
        p.x = obj.offsetLeft;
        p.y = obj.offsetTop;
        console.log(p);

        p.x = $(obj).width()/2;
        p.y = $(obj).height()/2;   
        console.log(p)    
        return p;
    }
```

Comment: hi, thanks but it not runs, with chrome ispector, this is the error: http://imageshack.com/a/img839/3616/hyhv.png

Comment: i've edited the code with offset.left and offset.top but it gives me another error: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'left' of undefined `